# angular 2 shared service passing object

Tags: angular, service

I'm new with angular 2. I'm working on my first project. It's a budget calculator built with 5 forms in different components and a summary as the last component.
I'm having a problem to figure it out how to create a shared service and passing data from any form to the summary component. 
If you look at the version number 14 of this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/KOSmVSMSnEvtfH4gplBQ?p=preview there is a simple working version of what I'm working on. 
In the same plunker version 15 you can find what I'm trying to achieve. Hope someone can help.
PageOneComponent

```
`import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { DataService } from '../dataservice';

@Component({
  template: `<h3>Page One </h3>
  <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" type="number" />
  <select  name="selectedPayFrequency" [(ngModel)]="selectedPayFrequency" 
  (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let p of payFrequencies" [ngValue]="p"> {{p.name}} </option>
  </select>
  <input [(ngModel)]="hero.prova" type="number" />
  <h1>{{newTotalIncome()}}</h1>
  <br />
  `,
})
export class PageOneComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  hero: Hero = {
    name: 0,
    prova:0,

  }; 

  constructor(public dataservice: DataService) {}

  payFrequencies = [{'name': 'per Month','value':1}, {'name': 'per Year', 'value':1/12}];
  selectedPayFrequency = this.payFrequencies[0];
  onChange(payFrequency) {
    return(payFrequency.value);
  }
  ngOnInit() { 

}
  ngOnDestroy() {

    this.dataservice.hero = this.hero; 
  }

  newTotalIncome(){
  return ((this.hero.name* this.selectedPayFrequency.value )*this.hero.prova)}
  }`
```

My major problem is finding a way to pass the selectedPayFrequency through the service. 
Here the service code

```
`import { Hero } from './hero';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  public hero: Hero;

}`
```

and here the Hero class 
    `export class Hero {
      name: number;
      prova:number;

```
 }`
```

summary component

```
`import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { DataService } from '../dataservice';

@Component({
  template: `<h3>Page Two: Data taken from page one.</h3>
  <span>{{newTotalIncome()}}</span>
  <br />`,
})
export class PageTwoComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  hero: Hero; 

  constructor(public dataservice: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.hero = this.dataservice.hero; 
  }

  ngOnDestroy() { 
  }

}`
```

Comment: I can't find the version 15 of the plunker you shared. Please share the link. Also, there are couple of ways of setting up shared services. It depends how the components are related. I'll get into that after I can take a look at version 15.

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/Oy3rv5wZE0JleNGwtn8a/  Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the five form components are isolated and don't depend on each other's data, then a shared service can created where the service is updated from each form and summary page displays the data.

Sample code:

```
export class Form1 {

  fd;
  input: any;

  constructor(private appState: AppState){
    this.fd = this.appState.getData();
  }

  save(val){
    this.fd.push({"form1" : val});
    this.appState.setData(this.fd);
  }

}
```

sample service:

```
export class AppState {

  public formData = [];

  setData(value){
    this.formData = value;
  }

  getData(){
    return this.formData;
  }

}
```

Here's a simple working [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/FWoNtfE4ic3Hi6RdCMsc?p=preview). You can enhance it to fit your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My form is quite complex but it works finally.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [**Observable**](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html) element: 

Add to the service "import { Observable } from 'rxjs';" 
Add EventEmitter to the component: "import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

That way you create a situation where the service is waiting for data (observable) and the form is sending it by $emit function whenever you need.